# command prompt "Access Denied" when trying to create "dir /b file.csv"

Tags: vba, excel, command-prompt

I am trying to create a VBA script which locates a directory and creates a .csv containing the names of all files in that directory.

I can successfully do this manually by shift + right clicking the folder > open command prompt > "dir /b > file.csv"

However, when I try to implement in my script using the below command line I get an access denied error. Any help on identifying this error is appreciated.

command is: `dir /b [Folderpath] > [PathtoFile]`

[image: Access Denied Error]

Thank you,

Comment: What VBA code have you tried?

Comment: "*Access denied*" means access denied! Either to your `[Folderpath]` or to `[PathtoFile]`. And in your screenshot `[PathtoFile]` is a folder not a file so maybe that's the issue. Also your screenshot looks more like `dir [Folderpath] /b > [PathtoFile]` than like you said above `dir /b [Folderpath] > [PathtoFile]`

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I did the code again as I wrote it previously and still got the access denied error.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you would need a CSV file when there is only 1 column of information, but this should do the trick if you want it done with VBA. Adjust `sFolder` to be the folder you want to look in.

```
Public Sub MakeFileCSV()
  Dim sFiles() As String
  ReDim sFiles(0)
  Const sFolder = "C:\"
  Dim sOutput As String
  sOutput = "C:\Users\" & Environ$("Username") & "\Desktop\Output.csv"
  Dim sFilename As String
  Dim nIndex As Integer

  ' read the files
  sFilename = Dir(sFolder)
  Do Until sFilename = ""
    ReDim Preserve sFiles(UBound(sFiles) + 1)
    sFiles(UBound(sFiles)) = sFilename
    sFilename = Dir()
  Loop

  ' output data
  Open sOutput For Output As #1
  For nIndex = 1 To UBound(sFiles)
    Print #1, sFiles(nIndex)
  Next
  Close #1

  MsgBox "done"

End Sub
```